# Python dataframe splitting into multiple based on column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

Below is my current dataframe FinalData which I read from excel:
[image]

Now I want to split the datframe into two, one dataframe which contain all the rows with zero or nan range, rest of the rows in another dataframe. How can I accomplish this, I tried the below code but is not working

amountzeroNanDf=FinalData [FinalData ['range']==0 | FinalData ['range']==np.nan]

restDatframe=FinalData[FinalData ['range']!=0 | FinalData ['range']!=np.nan]

Expected output:
amountzeroNanDf:[image]

restDatframe:[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Hi friend I am new to python, actually my problem is I have a data frame with two columns with multiple rows. The column 'range' in above excel can have nan, 0 or any positive or negative values. I want to split the data frame into two. First dataframe with all rows with range value 0 or nan. Rest of the rows into another  dataframe. can you suggest me any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
restDataFrame = FinalData[FinalData.range != 0.0].dropna()
amountzeroNanDf = FinalData.drop(FinalData[(FinalData['range'] > 0.0) | (FinalData['range'] < 0.0)].index)
```

Answer (score 0):

For rows with Zero or Nan values

```
amountzeroNanD = FinalData[(FinalData['range'].isnull()) | (FinalData['range'] ==0)]
```

Rest of the Rows

```
restDatframe =FinalData[(FinalData['range']!=0) & (FinalData['range'].notnull())]
```